# How is Dropout implemented in the Training Algorithm?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization, backpropagation, dropout

I've searched for an answer to this, and read a number of scientific articles on the subject, but I can't find a practical explanation of how Dropout actually drops nodes in an algorithm.

I've read that Dropout zeros out the activation function for particular nodes, that makes sense in the forward pass. But how does this work for the backward pass?

Comment: Look at the "inverse dropout" it clarified things for me a lot. In effect back-prop just uses the "non-zeroed" connections.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thank you, can you give me a link to a good resource on the topic?

Comment: In addition to the duplicate questions discovered using a site search, one can find an answer in the original Dropout paper, which has a whole section about how backprop works using dropout. [Dropout: A Simple Way to Prevent Neural Networks from
Overfitting](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rsalakhu/papers/srivastava14a.pdf)
Nitish Srivastava et al.

Comment: Thank you, I was directed to the paper preceding that one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0580, which is the origination of the confusion!

Comment: I wrote an answer to this here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/117082/how-can-i-implement-dropout-in-scikit-learn/117083#117083